# Excel Conditional Formatting for Highlighting rows

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements

I am trying to set up conditional formatting to highlight rows based on how far past a date a column is.

I have Columns A:Q, with dates within columns A, B and Q.

Formula I'm using in the Conditional Formatting rule is

```
=AND ( $Q3 < TODAY(),$Q3>=(TODAY()-2))
```

Here are the results I'm getting:

[image]

First column has the dates and the results from the conditional formatting, second column has the formula from the conditional formatting.  I'm at a loss for why it seems like random rows have been highlighted, when it appears the formula is correct for what I want.
Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What range is the rule applied to? Looks like there's a mismatch between the formula you used, specifically the `3` in `$Q3`, and the first row of the range the rule affects.

Comment: That is exactly correct.  The data starts on the 3rd row so I thought I needed the formatting to start on the 3rd row...after an hour of banging my head on it I just changed the 3 to a 1 and now it works correctly.  Thanks!